# Bitfield invalid - I don't know what to do discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Every time I start the bot, I get this error:

```
    throw new DiscordjsRangeError(ErrorCodes.BitFieldInvalid, bit);
    ^

RangeError [BitFieldInvalid]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: undefined.
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:168:11)
    at /home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:54
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at IntentsBitField.resolve (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:163:40)
    at new BitField (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/BitField.js:33:38)
    at new IntentsBitField (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/util/IntentsBitField.js:9:1)
    at Client._validateOptions (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:491:25)
    at new Client (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/Client.js:78:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/william/Cloud-Daddy/index.js:9:16)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14) {
  code: 'BitFieldInvalid'
}
```

but where it references my index.js line 9 column 16 is my

```
const client = new Discord.Client({
```

so I don't know what's going on.

I tried recoding but it still didn't work so I don't know.

My discord.js version is 14.7.1

Comment: What intents did you set when creating the client?

Comment: ```GatewayIntentBits.GUILDS, GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MEMBERS, GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_BANS, GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_WEBHOOKS,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_INVITES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_PRESENCES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGES,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING,
GatewayIntentBits.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
GatewayIntentBits.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
GatewayIntentBits.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING,
GatewayIntentBits.GUILD_PRESENCES;```

Comment: i even tried just using the guilds one and the message one and still didn't work

Comment: What's your discord.js version?

Comment: im using version 9.5.1

Comment: That's brutal :) You should definitely update that.

Comment: sorry that was npm version mine is 14.7.1

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try removing all bitfields and then adding them one by one and running your application to see which bitfields are invalid.

Make sure that you have all the required libraries imported at the start because I see that it says undefined for the invalid bitfield.

You can always read more and try to do step-by-step with the official discord.js guide: [Guide for discord.js 14](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/main-file.html#running-your-application)

Comment: bro its still not working i have the code in it and it wont work it has a proble with my the word "new" in that sentence

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: the version im using is 9.5.1

Comment: lmao that was npm version my discord.js is 14.7.1

Comment: Tam Thai npm is version 9 im on version 14.7.1